# why nothing happen when I reset the frame of a view controller in the navigation controller

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

assume view controller 1 is  a view controller pushed in a navigation controller ,And I change
the frame of the view controller 1 ,but it makes no difference. the view still full of the screen . did anyone knows why

Comment: UIViewControllers are intended to be full-screen display only. Pushing one onto the navigation stack means that that view **controller** is now in **control** of the **view**. With the iPad, it is slightly different as there has been introduced classes to split the view into multiple controllers.

Answer (score 0):

@Virgil i did a bit research on your question and found that when we push a view controller onto navigation controller the frame of the view controller is resized . i think this is the reason why we can not change the frame of the view controller's view , for more detailed study refer the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)